# Ошибка при попытке записать dataframe в базу данных из pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Я получаю json из HDFS, преобразую его и пытаюсь записать df в базу данных. 
Ошибка:

```
 at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

> Spark version: 2.3.1 PySpark: 2.3.1

Code:

```
df.write \
    .jdbc("jdbc:clickhouse://adqm2.gu.local:8123", "esia_dev.bill_agg_test",
          properties={"user": "user", "password": "password"})
```

Code2

```
df.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .mode("append") \
    .option("driver", "ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseDriver") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:clickhouse://adqm2.gu.local:8123/esia_dev")\
    .option("driver", "ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseDriver")\
    .option("dbtable", "esia_dev.bill_agg_test")\
    .option("user", "user") \
    .option("password", "password")\
    .save()
```

**P.S Я получаю ту же самую ошибку при попытке выгрузить csv*

Comment: Это не ошибка, а часть стектрейса. Добавьте текст самой ошибки.

Comment: @AlexChermenin, да ошибка связана с тем что класс драйвера в спарке не найден, при этом он появляется в приложении спарка (как класс добавленный пользователем), но при попытке к нему обратиться спарк его не видит. Это если напрямую через jupyter тетрадку, попытаться обратиться, через оператор airflow работает, поэтому вопрос уже неактуален